# javax.net.ssl.sslhandshakeexception handshake failed in huawei phones

Tags: java, android

I need help, in Huawei phones(version 4.4.2).
I have an error :

> javax.net.ssl.sslhandshakeexception handshake failed and can't connect
>   to the server.

I tested all solutions below like :

1- use com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1.

2- `ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(this);`
 
and so on.

How can repair this error ??

Comment: there is any solution to solve that please ?

Comment: Is there ProviderInstaller alternative in Huawei HMS? Or is it needed?

Comment: When you get an exception, log the *exception.* This is clearly some error message of your own devising, and no use whatsoever. At least give us a stack trace.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below for HMS

```
SecComponentInstallWizard.install(context)
```

Comment: You can use it how? Why? What problem does it solve? And how does it solve it?

Comment: It is the HMS equivalent of "ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(this); "